# Pass ID of object from django model

Tags: python, django

Here is my `test`

```
def someTest(self):

        # create an object 
        sampleModel.objects.create(unique_id='999999')

        # add code here to pass the sampleModel object created above to view:page1

        # Make sure the sampleModel object created appears in page 1
        response = self.client.get(reverse('view:page1'))  # check that above created mlab appears
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

How can I modify my test to check that the `sampleModel` object created appears in `view:page1` ? The goal of the test to check if created objects appear in page1.

Here is my `urls.py`

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.sampleView.as_view(), name='page1'),
```

Comment: It depends what your view does. You could use `self.assertContains(response, 'some text')` if you expect specific text to be shown, or you could test the `context` of the `response` if you render a django template (`self.assertTrue(response.context['sample'])` or `self.assertEqual(response.context['sample']['id'], '999999')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the data get inside the template looks as they should looks like:

```
self.assertContains(response, '999999')
self.assertContains(response, 'another field value')
```

Or check directly the context returned by the view itself:

```
self.assertEqual(response.context['object_name']['field_name'], 'value_of_the_field'))
```

Edit here is the code:

```
def someTest(self):

        # create an object 
        sample = sampleModel.objects.create(unique_id='999999')

        # add code here to pass the sampleModel object created above to view:page1

        # Make sure the sampleModel object created appears in page 1
        response = self.client.get(reverse('view:page1', kwargs={'pk':sample.pk}))  
        # check that above created mlab appears
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        #other stuff to test depending of what your view return.
```

Comment: I cannot seem to pass the object i.d into reverse correctly, I did `response = self.client.get(reverse('view:page1'), kwargs={'page1': new_object.id}) ` and I got `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'page1' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['page1\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

Comment: `self.client.get(reverse('view:page1'), kwargs={'pk': new_object.id})` It needs to be what the urls are expecting

Comment: unfortunelty I get this error
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'page1 with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['overview\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

Comment: unfortuneltey I cannot get it work, is there something I can provide to clarify this usse ?

Comment: the kwargs need to be inside reverse look at the edit